# Safely setup Sha256 keys in the keychain - iOS APP

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I would like to secure the communication from my APP to the server with Sha256.
For this I need some common keys on either side (APP/Server).

How do I get these keys into the keychain without setting them up as plaintext when storing them? No point in having them in the keychain if the APP can be decompiled and the keys are visible in plain text anyway.

The plan was also to have a password and username for communication verification. Both stored in the keychain, and the password as just the Sha256 key stored in the keychain and not the actual password.

I would still like to secure my Sha keys.

Comment: So, you use this key for secured communication channel and authentication?

Comment: I would use these keys for the hashing to validate that the data has not been manipulated